# Comparing DateTime.Now to value stored in SQL

Tags: c#

I am converting `ADODB` namespace code to `SqlClient`. I am trying to replace code that utilized `recordset.Value`.  I am having problems converting this line of code. How can I subtract `DateTime.Now` from the value in the `time_of_lock` (Datetime data type) column in `SQL`?

```
else if (DateTime.Now - rs.Fields["time_of_lock"].Value < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You should specify to us the data type of that column, too.

Comment: @MattU I am getting away from `ADODB`

Comment: It is the kind of statement that works in vb.net with Option Strict Off in effect.  The compiler then automatically generates the code to convert the Value property from Object to DateTime.  C# is strict only, you have to use Convert.ToDateTime() explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you can get two `DateTime` values from your code. If so, try pop both into the following function:

```
private bool TimesApartNoMoreThan(DateTime first, DateTime second, int threshold) 
{
    return (second - first).TotalMinutes > threshold;
}
```

when you subtract two DateTimes, [you get a TimeSpan](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=netframework-4.8). Having obtained that, you can represent it as whatever unit of duration you need ([in this case, minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.8)):

Comment: The first value would be `DateTime.Now` and the second would be the value in the time_of_lock column

Comment: Do you mind sharing a reproducible code sample so we could get some context please?

Answer (score -1):

From your statement, I am assuming  rs.Fields["time_of_lock"] is of DateTime datatype. If that is the case, please try this:

```
DateTime.Now .Subtract(rs.Fields["time_of_lock"].Value).TotalMinutes < 15
```

Comment: what is `(lockedAt.Value)`?

Comment: @Rb428 Updated my answer.